# Unwrap not joining the torso front, back and head UV

Tags: uv

When I unwrapped the model after applying the mirror it didn't connected the head, torso and back as you can see in the image, is there any config for this to happen?  [image]

I wanted it to look something like this so I texturize it properly ↓

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, the middle vertices (yellow) were duplicated after I applied the mirror, if anyone get the same problem, just delete them and fill the holes again ^^

[image]

Comment: Quicker to select all with 'A' and then Merge by distance in this case.

Comment: ..or select and adjust merge settings on the mirror modifier before applying.

Comment: Oh, thank you all, it's great to know these options, I'm new to blender so I still don't know much ^^